# Are custom error pages possible on Azure App Service slots?

Tags: azure, express, azure-web-app-service, custom-error-pages

I'm trying to build a "maintenance mode" screen for Azure App Services running a single-page Vue app. Is this possible without Application Gateway?

#### Background

- Azure App Service instance
- Runs a Node Express server on startup
- Express serves up a single page app
- All data is fed into the SPA via an API
- When the API undergoes maintenance I need a way to tell the front-end
- I'd prefer not to ask the API if it's available for each page view

#### Ideas and things we've tried

I know Azure Application Gateway can serve up custom error pages, but we're currently not using this service and might have some legal/data privacy issues (it's a healthcare tool) with its data caching requirements.

I added a `web.config` file to the `wwwroot` on the service slot as an attempt to catch errors and redirect but it seems to have no impact. This is what I expected since Express should be handling routing and errors (which it does).

Asure has the ability to "stop a slot". Is there any way to customize the page that's displayed?

Other web searches show that custom errors were requested at one point, but the [Azure feature request page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/9912714-enable-users-to-create-custom-error-pages-for-403) produces a very beautiful 404 page (oh the irony).

**Is there a way to customize the `stopped` and/or server error pages in Azure? Are there other commonly accepted ways of solving a problem like this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom Error page is only available by using the Application Gateway. This feature is not available Without Application Gateway. If you want this feature please add your feed back/Feature request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community)

You can catch the http errors only by using `web.config` in `wwwroot` directory by adding below code

```
< httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
< remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
< error statusCode="404" path="/public/CustomError.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
< /httpErrors>
```

On above snippet of code can redirect to the CustomError.html if any html error occurred.
Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44317476/custom-static-error-page-with-node-and-azure-webapp)